# Printing output on textfield

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, jtextfield

Can someone help me? My question is how can I print all the output inside a textfield?

```
System.out.print("Enter sentence");
word = input.nextLine();
word= word.toUpperCase();

String[] t = word.split(" ");

for (String e : t)
    if(e.startsWith("A")){

        JFrame f= new JFrame ("Output");
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel (e);

        f.add(lbl);
        f.setSize(300,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Comment: Create a `JTextField` and use the method `setText(text);`

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted will make crazy things: you are creating and showing a new frame **every time** you find a string starting with "A".
You should create the frame **just once**, for example you can prepare the output before creating the frame by concatenating the desidered elements of 't' array.
Then you create the frame adding a JTextField with the desired text. You might prefer to have the output printed in different lines into a textarea.
If you use a textarea you can also use append method (look example below).

Remember that

```
setVisible(true)
```

should be the last instruction when you create a JFrame, or you could have an undesired behaviour, especially if you try to add components to the frame after calling it.
Also, it's better to call pack() method on the JFrame than setting size manually.

Look the example below to see how you could solve your problem :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.print("Enter sentence");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = input.nextLine().toUpperCase(); 
        String[] t = word.split(" ");
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String separator = System.lineSeparator(); // decide here the string used to separate your output, you can use "" if you don't want to separate the different parts of the array 't'
                JFrame f = new JFrame ("Output");
                // First solution: use a JTextArea
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
                textArea.setEditable(false); // you might want to turn off the possibilty to change the text inside the textArea, comment out this line if you don't
                textArea.setFocusable(false); // you might want to turn off the possibility to select the text inside the textArea, comment out this line if you don't
                for (String e : t) if(e.startsWith("A")) textArea.append(e + separator);
                f.add(textArea);
                // Second solution: If you still want to have all the output into a textfield, replace the previous 5 lines of code with the following code :
                // separator = " ";  // in this case don't use a newline to separate the output
                // String text = "";
                // for (String e : t) if(e.startsWith("A")) text += e + separator;
                // f.add(new JTextField(text));
                // f.setSize(300,200);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```